# Google Apps Script - Automatically put the Time (GMT), Time (Am/Pm) and the Date in different Column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, time, datetime-format

Whenever there is "Time Date" Format in the Timestamp Column, I Want the "Time (GMT)", "Time (Am/Pm)" and the "Date" of that "Timestamp" to be stated in different Columns in some selected sheets "Sheet 1, Sheet2, etc" in Google Sheets using Apps Script. If the Timestamp column is empty then no error message should be in the "Stated columns - Time (GMT), Time (Am/Pm)"and the Date Columns" when the script is initialized.
Thank You

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `=T2` in each column and change the format to get the desired output.